# How to prevent re-render of leaf React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 components **A**, **B** and **C**.

**A** is the parent while **B** and **C** are children.
**B** is a text editor and **C** displays the result of a computation using the value from **B**.

**A** will store the value entered in **B** to forward it to **C**.

Is there a way to only re-render **C** when a value of **B** is changed?

```js
const A = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const updateText = (text) => {
    setText(text);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <B updateText={updateText} />
      <C text={text} />
    </>
  );
}

const B = (props) => {
  const updateText = (event) => {
    props.updateText(event.target.value);
  }

  return <input onChange={updateText}/>
}

const C = (props) => {
  return <p>{props.text}</p>;
}
```

Comment: What’s wrong with what you have?

Comment: You can use React.memo perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) on the component **B** which only re-renders when props change.

You also need to apply [`React.useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) on `updateText` that would help to prevent `updateText` getting re-initialized for every re-rendering.

```js
const A = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

  const updateText = React.useCallback((text) => {
    setText(text);
  }, [])

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
       <B updateText={updateText} />
       <C text={text} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const B = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log('rendered B');
  const updateText = (event) => {
    props.updateText(event.target.value);
  }

  return <input onChange={updateText}/>
})

const C = (props) => {
  console.log('rendered C');
  return <p>{props.text}</p>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <A/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```